# SQL Count how many column that have specific value in specific user

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have table in database like below:

| id | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF | ColG | USER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | **AB** | AA | AA | AA | **AB** | AA | userABC |

and i want to count how many 'AB' that userABC get.

So the result that i want as per below

| count AB |
| --- |
| 2 |

anyone know the query or keyword for this situation?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Use case expressions, one for each ColA - ColG.

Comment: [UnPivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) it then `count` it

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this with `sum` and `case` statements:

```
select sum(case when ColA = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when ColB = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when ColC = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when ColD = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when ColE = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when ColF = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end
+ case when ColG = 'AB' then 1 else 0 end) from table_name
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f76e3edb26e185c995d3aa5056731eb5)

Comment: thank u zak, for ur help.  one more, if i have multiple columns, is there any shortcut/query to calculate all AB values ​​in user ABC, other than declaring one by one like the case when ColA = 'AB' . column user is unique,

Comment: @ezles88 yup, can be done using dynamic sql. Check this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b58f236f2ed54405b8cb90cd3b7bd51)

Answer (score 2):

Unpivot the table using `VALUES` table value constructor and count the `AB`'s. If you want to get the count for each row, the following statement is an option:

```
-- Sample data
SELECT *
INTO TestTable
FROM (VALUES 
   (1, 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'userABC')
) t (id, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF, ColG, USER_ID)

-- T-SQL
SELECT 
   t.USER_ID,
   (
   SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM (VALUES (t.ColA), (t.ColB), (t.ColC), (t.ColD), (t.ColE), (t.ColF), (t.ColG)) v (Col)
   WHERE Col = 'AB'
   ) AS CountAB
FROM TestTable t
WHERE (t.USER_ID = 'userABC')
```

If the table has more than one row for one `USER_ID`, you need to group the rows:

```
-- Sample data
SELECT *
INTO TestTable
FROM (VALUES 
   (1, 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'userABC'),
   (2, 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'userABC'),
   (3, 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'userABC')
) t (id, ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF, ColG, USER_ID)

-- T-SQL
SELECT t.USER_ID, COUNT(a.Col) AS CountAB
FROM TestTable t
OUTER APPLY (VALUES 
   (t.ColA), (t.ColB), (t.ColC), (t.ColD), (t.ColE), (t.ColF), (t.ColG)
) a (Col)
WHERE (t.USER_ID = 'userABC') AND (a.Col = 'AB')
GROUP BY t.USER_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You could go from wide to tall format, and then aggregate by user:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT USER_ID, ColA AS val FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT USER_ID, ColB FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT USER_ID, ColC FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT USER_ID, ColD FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT USER_ID, ColE FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT USER_ID, ColF FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT USER_ID, ColG FROM yourTable
)

SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(*) AS [count AB]
FROM cte
WHERE val = 'AB'
GROUP BY USER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
Select Id, User_Id, ((Select Isnull(count(Id),0) from [Table] where ColA 
like'AB' and Id = A.Id) + 
(Select Isnull(count(Id),0) from [Table] where ColB = 'AB' and Id = A.Id) + 
(Select Isnull(count(Id),0) from [Table] where ColC = 'AB' and Id = A.Id) + 
(Select Isnull(count(Id),0) from [Table] where ColD = 'AB' and Id = A.Id) + 
(Select Isnull(count(Id),0) from [Table] where ColE = 'AB' and Id = A.Id) + 
(Select Isnull(count(Id),0) from [Table] where ColF = 'AB' and Id = A.Id) + 
(Select Isnull(count(Id),0) from [Table] where ColG = 'AB' and Id = A.Id) 
) as Result
from [Table] A
```